# Ubuntu 22.10 broken after update

Tags: kernel, updates, 22.10

A few days ago I updated Ubuntu 22.10 and when I rebooted the system I had the following issues:

1. The computer couldn't connect to the internet in any way (with wi-fi, with ethernet or with usb)
2. The bluetooth adapter wasn't detected either
3. The refresh rate of the screen was set to 60hz (normally it's in 144hz) and NVIDIA X Server settings is not detecting my GPU anymore

If I go to the advanced settings in GRUB, I can see that the system is booting in `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-1015-oracle`. If I boot in the other option available in the menu (`Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-29-generic`) everything works great again.
Is this some kind of issue with the Kernel? In that case, what should I do to fix it?

Edit: if I run `dkms status` in the working kernel it shows the following `xpad/0.4, 5.19.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed`
Just to clarify: I never tried to install any additional kernel or anything like that. I have no idea of what is this oracle kerneltree/oracle cloud infrastructure. I only installed some programs in .deb and flatpak packaging format but nothing else.
Could it be that this auto-installed by itself with the update or something like that? And should I do something to uninstall it?

Edit 2:
this is the output of `dpkg -l | grep oracle`:

```
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-1015-oracle                  5.19.0-1015.17                            amd64        Signed kernel image oracle  
ii  linux-modules-5.19.0-1015-oracle                5.19.0-1015.17                            amd64        Oracle Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP  
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1015-oracle     5.19.0-1015.17+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.19.0-1015 (objects)  
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1015-oracle      5.19.0-1015.17+1                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.19.0-1015-oracle
```

and this is the complete output of `sudo apt update`:

```
Obj:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Obj:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                           
Des:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease [109 kB]                   
Obj:4 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                                      
Obj:5 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease                                                              
Obj:6 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease                       
Obj:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Des:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [28,5 kB]
Des:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.436 B]
Descargados 139 kB en 2s (65,7 kB/s)          
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se pueden actualizar 33 paquetes. Ejecute «apt list --upgradable» para verlos.
```

Comment: Boot up the working kernel and show `dkms status` add this to your question please [edit]  and do you really need this oracle kerneltree?

Comment: Are you running on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure? If no, you should boot the normal kernel.

Comment: Can confirm - this happened to me too on a Lenovo P1 Gen2 and 22.10. 
Was suspicious about the kernel, your post helped me temporarily resolve this - choosing `29-generic` worked for me.
(GJ Google for indexing this so quick.) 

Seems like the `oracle` kernels are for Oracle Cloud systems, I do wonder why it was auto-installed on my machine.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1451352/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`. It may be lengthy -- show us all of it.

Comment: And also `dpkg -l | grep oracle` please.

Comment: The problem is in the kernel. What do you need the oracle kernel for? Delete it with apt purge.

Comment: Please remove the 4 packages with oracle in name.

Comment: I'm on a Dell XPS and had this also happen when pulling in normal updates today. Removing the Oracle kernel did the trick, you should write that as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Same thing happened to me on a Dell Precision with Ubuntu 23.04. I didn't look closely enough at the suggested updates and it installed an oracle kernel. I think this might be related to Nvidia driver updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `Advanced options for Ubuntu` on boot and choosing a non-`oracle` Kernel, the following command solved it for me permanently (by uninstalling all packages with 'oracle' in their name and its additional data files):

```bash
dpkg -l | grep oracle | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | while read line ; do sudo apt -y purge $line ; done;
```

You can also run the following command to confirm what will be removed, prior to running the purge command:

```bash
dpkg -l | grep oracle | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | while read line ; do echo "sudo apt purge $line" ; done;
```

P.S. - Pretty odd that some of those leaving comments above write to you as if you *chose* to install an Oracle Cloud kernel. :facepalm: Ubuntu in 2023..